# Origins of the word "terrible"

Tags: etymology, adjectives

What are the origins of the word "terrible". Do the words "terror" or "terrific" come from the same roots?

I am curious since I believe the word "terrible" can be used to mean "great" in French.

Comment: All your adjectives are belong to nous!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both *terrible* and *terrific* go back, through French and Latin to Proto Indo European roots meaning to shiver.  The origin is self explanatory: extreme fear being well known to provoke shivering.

To these two you can therefore add *tremor* and *tremble*.

In English "terrible" and "terrific" are antonyms.  *Terrific* means exceptionally good and on the contrary, *terrible* means exceptionally bad.

In French however, *terrific* does not exist and *terrible* has both significations.  Only the context, common sense or the status of the speaker will tell you which meaning to choose from.

If one says "c'est pas *terrible*", that will mean below average.
If a youngster says "this singer is *terrible*", that has to be understood as appreciative.

In "Ivan le terrible" though, the meaning is obviously not "the Great".

Comment: And "C'est terrible" would depend entirely on the context.

Comment: A bit like the English word "wicked" then.

Comment: From Lewis and Short: terreo - to frighten, affright, put in fear or dread, to alarm, terrify. ( http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=terrere&la=la&prior=vultu&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=aufero&i=1#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=terreo-contents )

Comment: A friend found the word *terrible* in her KJV Bible to describe God. She was confused and asked for my help. In its biblical setting it was obvious that the word described His awesomeness; it referred to God's greatness, not his "badness".

Answer (score 7):

- [*Terrible*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terrible) comes (through the Old French *terrible*) from the Latin *terribilis*, of the verb *terrere* (“fill with fear”)
- [*Terrific*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terrific) comes from the Latin *terrificus* (“causing fear”), built from *terrere* + *facere* (“make”) (this root of *facere* is the reason for the suffix *-ficus* in Latin, *-fique* in French and thus *-fic* in English).
- To go further, [*terror*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terror) comes from Old French *terreur*, from Latin *terror*, in turn from *terrere*.

So, both come from the same Latin verb.

---

<sup>To go even further, though it's off topic, the French *terrible* to mean “great” was very used in the language of *les précieuses*. The *[TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/tlf.htm)* calls this informal, though: *“Fam. [Empl. comme intensif; avec valeur méliorative] Sensationnel, extraordinaire, propre à susciter l'admiration.”* (Informal [Intensifier, meliorative] Sensational, outstanding, worthy of admiration.)</sup>