# Is the use of the word “terrible” in a positive sense at all common?

Tags: meaning, slang, connotation

I recently had an argument with one gentleman where he charged that he had heard the word *terrible* being used in a positive sense, as if something was good, or great. I had lived in the States for over 12 years where I was exposed to different strata of society from PhDs to lowly construction workers and warehouse serfs one of whom I was as well. I have heard people talk of all sorts of *bad*, *brutal*, *sick*, even *ill*, and generally *awesome* things, but I had never encountered the word *terrible* being used that way, even in this age of ironic hipsters.

In the question [about the origins of the word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/origins-of-the-word-terrible), few people pointed out that in French the word *terrible* does have a positive colloquial meaning, which is confirmed by several dictionaries. Likewise, English dictionaries acknowledge different meanings for the sister word *terrific* pointing that the meaning of *fantastic* and the like is informal, and the meaning of *inspiring terror* is archaic. But no respectable dictionary I had checked does mention any sort of ambiguity in regards of *terrible*.

The only source known to me as yet that acknowledges the positive sense of *terrible* is Urban Dictionary, and even there it has been [consistently downvoted](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=terrible). Yet, it still received some votes, so at least some people think there is a legitimacy to this claim. Is there anything to this at all? Is that some sort of new phenomenon, or is it utterly misguided? If it is indeed real, are there any examples of such usage in popular culture?

Comment: You should elaborate more about that. Maybe it depends on the situation, for example we can say *He is hell of a programmer*, *He is so good, his code is sick mate*. We can say *He knows terribly good jokes mate* and ect. In the last example terrible makes good in stronger form - pretty standard for English language.

Comment: @speedyGonzales, that is very different as _terribly_ is an adverb, and in an informal sense (that is [acknowledged by OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terribly?q=terribly), for instance) it means _very_. Thus it is an amplifier, not qualifier.

Comment: All I am saying is I work and understand better by example. For example your girlfriend is crying and you give her napkin and she says - *You are terrible* (like you are really good and I don't deserve you). In some of your resources it is said that terrible can mean above average.

Comment: There are zero "positive" hits on COCA. Examples of the word being used in the sense of _awe-inspiring_ or _formidable_ appear to be either dated or idiomatic. One could argue that this sense is also pseudo-positive at best.

Comment: @coleopterist, are you using corpus [hosted by BYU](http://www.americancorpus.org)? How do you search for “positives”?

Comment: @speedyGonzales, I wish she would think of me that way. :D But no, I cannot offer an example, because, as I said, myself I had never encountered it, but what you said, this is pretty much it.

Comment: @theUg Yes, that's the one. Re: "positives", I scanned through the top 100 results manually.

Comment: I suppose it depends on [which side of the sword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_Hymn_of_the_Republic#Lyrics) you find yourself. But *terrible* in English is hard to construe in a positive light for anyone.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen *terrible* used in the sense of "awe inspiring" on a number of occasions, though typically the sense would be reasonably neutral vs truly positive.  However, I'm certain I've heard it used positively a few times (though unfortunately I can't point at an example).

Comment: Doesn’t Galadriel say this about herself in Lord of the Rings, when she comes in contact with the One Ring at the fountain in Lothlorien?

Comment: Ivan the Terrible was a good czar.  Unless he was angry at you.

Answer (score 5):

The OED’s first definition is ‘causing or fit to cause terror; inspiring great fear or dread. Also: awe-inspiring, awesome’, but the only citation that might be thought to use ‘terrible’ in a positive sense is this from Swinburne ‘Superb instances of terrible beauty undeformed by horrible detail.’ Yeats uses the word in a similar way in this line (not in the OED) from ‘Easter 1916’: ‘A terrible beauty is born.’

The answer in brief is that *terrible* only rarely has anything other than a negative sense, and that if we use it in any other way we need to know what we’re doing, and, in particular, we need to be sure that our readers or listeners will understand how we’re using it.

Comment: I wouldn't even say that Yeats' and Swinburne's use was positive, but rather the neutral sense, (with the negative sense evoked in Yeats' and arguably also in Swinburne's), held in tension with a positive noun.

Comment: +1 "only rarely has anything other than a negative sense"

Comment: The Swinburne quote is about the tragic drama of John Ford and the power of its language which Swinburne compares to a "burning blast". The Yeats poem is about a failed revolution that Yeats supported, listing the dead who had left behind their trivial lives to become part of something meaningful and hence beautiful, notwithstanding their executions for treason. So not exactly positive uses of "terrible".

Answer (score 5):

Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) lists multiple instances in which *terrible* (or *turrible*) serves as an "adjective-for-adverb" intensifier along the lines of *extremely* and thus achieves a positive or negative sense only by its contextual association:

> **terrible** ... **2.** *adv.* Terribly, very. [Relevant examples of contextually positive use:] **1903 s.e. M[issouri].** Common 'He is a turrible fine man.' Much used by North Carolinians, 'Very' seldom used. 'Mighty,' or 'monstrous,' or 'turrible' takes its place. 'Quite' is almost unknown, 'right' taking its place. ... **1929 Maine coast.** A hilly view was 'turrible sightly.' ... **1938 Fl[orida]–G[eorgia] Suwannee R[iver].** Turrible good. ...

But Wentworth also notes the use of *terrible* in Newfoundland as an adjective with an exclusively (and extremely) positive sense:

> **3.** *adj.* Wonderful. **1921 Newfoundland** [Example:] Terrible cures.

It's highly unlikely that Newfoundland dialect influenced U.S. slang to any significant degree. Nevertheless, Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960) has this entry for *terrible*:

> **terrible** *adj.* Wonderful; great; the best; the most. 1957: "Terrible—The best; the greatest." E[[lliott] Home, *For Cool Cats and Far-Out Chicks. Some far-out use.*

The identical entry appears in the second edition of *Dictionary of American Slang* (1975), but the third edition (1995) drops it. The piece by Home was actually a jazz glossary that appeared in *New York Times Magazine* (August 18, 1957). Home's glossary entry appears in identical form in [*The Jazz Word*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ToYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22terrible+the+best+the+greatest%22&dq=%22terrible+the+best+the+greatest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzlJ7ggYDKAhVHKGMKHbmOCc8Q6AEIJzAC) (1962) and in [*Dizzy, Duke, the Count and Me: The Story of the Monterey Jazz Festival*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9IUwAQAAIAAJ&q=%22terrible+the+best+the+greatest%22&dq=%22terrible+the+best+the+greatest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzlJ7ggYDKAhVHKGMKHbmOCc8Q6AEIITAB) (1978). I didn't find a similar definition of *terrible* in any of the other slang dictionaries I consulted.

So confirmed instances of a purely positive, context-independent sense of *terrible* do exist, but they are specific to 1931 Newfoundlanders and 1957 jazz cool cats (and far-out chicks). The fact that this positive sense of *terrible* is attested in two seemingly unrelated dialects suggests that it may arise (or have arisen) in other specific subcultures as well, but so far it appears not to have come into general use with that meaning in British or North American English.

Answer (score 3):

If the word *terrible* is being used much in a positive way, even as a slang term, it has not been noticed by the lexicographers. Up to now, the least negative sense of *terrible* is as an intensifier, as in

> **1853** K<sub><sup>ANE</sup></sub> *Grinnell Exp.* xxxiv. (1856) 301 Even you, terrible worker as you are, could not study in the Arctic regions.[¹](http://archive.org/stream/oed9barch#page/n623/mode/2up)

and even this example conjures up a sense of an overwhelming, possibly frightening, force of will. One may even be reminded of Mary Shelley’s monster, who has such terrible strength that he is able to sustain his life in the Arctic.

Barry England is careful in his answer not to make much of his Swinburne and Yeats citations

> the only citation that might be thought to use ‘terrible’ in a positive sense is this from Swinburne ‘Superb instances of terrible beauty undeformed by horrible detail.’ Yeats uses the word in a similar way in this line … from ‘Easter 1916’: ‘A terrible beauty is born.’[²](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102886/14073)

and that is just as well. These are both incontestably *terrible* in the usual sense, juxtaposed with *beauty* to create a contrast for rhetorical effect. Yeats’ “terrible beauty” juxtaposes the *terrible* execution of revolutionaries with the *beauty* (as he saw it) of their sacrifice on behalf of the Irish people.[³](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter,_1916) He could just as easily have written “dreadful beauty”. In the same way, Swinburne’s “terrible beauty” juxtaposes the *beauty* of certain dramatic poetry with its *terrible* subject, specifically that of Cyril Tourneur

> which makes *incision in the memory* … the grandest verses of Marston or Chapman … have less of *cautery in their stroke*

and that of John Webster

> in his handling of *criminal and terrible matter*.[⁴](http://books.google.com/books?id=0FoLAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA311&ots=zSjk0-C8mf&dq=Superb%20instances%20of%20terrible%20beauty%20undeformed%20by%20horrible%20detail&pg=PA310#v=onepage&q=Superb%20instances%20of%20terrible%20beauty%20undeformed%20by%20horrible%20detail&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in some parts (of some translations) of the Bible, God is referred to as being "terrible" in a sense that is generally positive.  In this case it would be very akin to "awesome".

Comment: I don’t believe it to be positive. Biblical and theological texts forsooth refer to Christian god as “great and terrible” with frequency, but I do think the meaning is literal: “God is great, and should be revered, but he is also terrible, thus he should be feared”.

Comment: @theUg Sure, but it's *very* different from how most folk use terrible, which is simply as a synonym for "extremely bad".   I was thinking that this might be what the gentleman you talked to might have meant.  Also, awesome used to be pretty directly synonymous with terrible, since awe meant terror or fright.

Comment: The idea that forms of יָרֵא should be translated “awesome” instead of “terrible” is a modern conceit. It is used throughout the OT with the sense of “terror”. The first use of it is Genesis 3:10: “I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I [was] naked; and I hid myself.” Remember, God is cast as a king; the idea that one should not be terrified in the presence of one’s king is a modern conceit also, possible only because the king no longer has real power.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a usage that is closer to what you mean - sort of mock admiration

[ngram - you are terrible](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+are+terrible+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

*The Brooklyn Novels - Page 846* Daniel Fuchs, Jonathan Lethem - 1961 -

> "You are terrible," she said, "simply terrible. Shurtee, I don't know vat I vill ever do vith you. How do you like the negligee?" He sucked in his breath. "Gorgeous!"

[image]

---

As an adverb, I have heard it often. Especially in older movies spoken by posh people...

For example: *The new etiquette: the modern code of social behavior - Page 192*

> Just the other day I heard a lovely, but thoughtless, girl say of her dancing partner, "He's terribly clever." Since "terribly" is derived from "terror," one might have supposed that the young man was engaged in inventing machines of torture instead

[ngram - terribly clever](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=terribly+clever&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

Comment: I already noted it in the different comment, that I am not interested in an **adverb** _terribly_ used as the amplifier, equivalent to the word _very_. This is known usage, and reflected in the dictionaries.

Comment: See update - I was not ready :)

Comment: Yes, I think that can accurately be described as "mock terror". That only works, of course, because "terrible" means "engendering terror". It is not gaining a neutral sense, just being used in an ironic context.

Answer (score 1):

It's use in neutral senses is rare enough these days. And I have never heard it used in a full positive sense.

I am though reminded of several times when a colleague has caused consternation among partners from other countries when they described something as "deadly"; a highly positive term in my city and a few other parts of the country, but not found as such elsewhere.

Conversely, once when a film was set here the PR people paid more attention to the local press than would be usual because they were particularly interested in the opinions of those who knew the film's setting. They were delighted when one newspaper described it as "brutal" and put that quote on the film's posters, because a gritty brutal atmosphere had been exactly what they intended. Had they though translated from slangy style the review was written in, into received English, the quote would have read "of embarrassingly poor quality". (Or into modern internet slang, "FAIL!").

So while I've never heard "terrible" in a fully positive sense, I am more than willing to believe that there may be a small demographic somewhere that uses it exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Growing up in the 70's I used to hear
My mom use "terrible" like we use "bad" to mean good. She would say "Anne had on terrible suit", which meant Anne had on a "bad" suit,both of which meant the suit was awesome. Since then, Ive only heard it used to mean good from people of my moms generation. My mom is 68.

Comment: Hello, user153076, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer is intriguing but not detailed enough to provide as useful an anecdotal piece of evidence as it might. You could make it stronger by identifying the city or region and country where your mother grew up and (if different) where she lived while you were growing up. Also—because it comes up in research that I did into this question—I would be interested to know whether she was conversant in jazz slang or any other subculture lingo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cognomen of the Russian Tsar Ivan Grozny is usually translated as "Ivan the Terrible" but it means something closer to "formidable", "awe-inspiring". The capital of Chechnya has the same name.

Comment: My Social Studies teacher said she preferred to think of him as "Ivan the Awful".

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard people use the word "terrible" with a positive meaning. I study ancient Greek, so this habit made me think about the Greek verb "thaumazein", which means "to be frightened", but also "to be amazed". I think that this verb and the word "terrible" share the same root and the same ambivalence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Your observation is interesting, but it could be more informative if you provided links to sources about the etymology of the two words. You may want to visit the site's Help Center to read about standards for writing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

A source said: 'No one is terribly fond of Clarence House because it's still seen very much as the Queen Mother's place.'

The use of the positive adjective, in this case as overly, is common in upper crust language.

Comment: This is the adverb *terribly*. The usage of this is very different from that of the adjective *terrible* which the OP asked about.